# Compiler error depending on parameter position in method signature. Use of unassigned local variable

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, language-design, compiler-construction

Let's say I have this class:

```
class Boo
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "I am Boo!";
    }
}
```

And these methods:

```
static int Foo(out Boo boo)
{
    boo = new Boo();
    return 1;
}
static void Lol(Boo boo, int n)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n);
    Console.WriteLine(boo);
}
```

Now in Main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Boo boo;
    Lol(boo, Foo(out boo));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This gives a compilation error: **Use of unassigned local variable 'boo'**. First of all, I understand why this is happening, I can fix it by adding:

```
Boo boo = null;
```

Then, in my **Lol** method, boo remains null in spite of **Foo** being executed first. Then if I modify my code to use **ref** like this:

```
Lol(ref boo, Foo(out boo));
static void Lol(ref Boo boo, int n)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n);
    Console.WriteLine(boo);
}
```

I got **I am Boo!** as expected. What I do not understand is why if I change the order of the parameters in **Lol** and without using ref and without initializing **boo** like this:

```
static void Lol(int n, Boo boo) //order of the parameters has changed
{
    Console.WriteLine(n);
    Console.WriteLine(boo);
}

Lol(Foo(out boo), boo);
```

Then this does not give any compilation error and besides I got "I am Boo!" as expected.

While debugging I noticed that in both cases (having int parameter as first one and having the other way) Foo is executed first. Then why the compiler is showing this error?

Comment: @ToastGeek, please read all, that is not true, after changing the order of the parameters it is not necesary to initialize the variable as I showed. And I got expected results =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler evaluates the argument expressions from left to right. So in this line:

```
Boo boo = null;
Lol(boo,Foo(out boo));
```

(without `ref`) `boo` is evaluated first (which results in `null`) and this result *value* (`null`) is put on the stack as argument for `Lol`.

Then `Foo(out boo)` is executed which sets the value of your local `boo` variable but does not change the value already on stack for `Lol`.

---

Using `ref` a *reference* to your local `boo` variable is put on the stack, so `Lol` will read the value as changed by `Foo`.

---

When changing the order of parameters, `Foo(out boo)` is evaluated/executed first and `boo` is initialized before it's value is put on the stack for `Lol`.

Comment: Thanks! That explains why! Wouldn't be better if the compiler could resolve this and not throwing errors? Because, let's say it compiles, I somehow trick the compiler, then I would not have runtime errors as Foo is executed first in both cases. Just saying...